# Passing variables to template in custom controller without GET/POST request params

Tags: twig, shopware

I have a specific problem where I have to pass variable to template in custom controller, but I couldn't use `POST` or `GET` request (reason being that function that's doing redirect only sends `GET` request, and I don't want params to be visible to the end user).

Is there a way to set global variable and attach it to context or a session? I also tried to use `RequestDataBag`, but after redirect I couldn't access previously set data.

Here's what I tried to do:

```php
public function pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): RedirectResponse
{
    $returnUrl = $transaction->getReturnUrl();

    $dataBag->add(['test' => 'test1']);

    return new RedirectResponse('/checkout/confirm/custom-controller');
}
```

and tried to catch it in controller:

```php
public function cliffMarketsBerrySimplify(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context, RequestDataBag $dataBag)
{
    $data = $dataBag->get('test');

    return $this->renderStorefront('@plugin/storefront/page/checkout/payment/custom-template.html.twig');
}
```

But `$data` is empty. Is there other way to approach this problem. Is it possible to set global context variable or attach variable to session and then retrieve it?

Comment: What's the business / use case of this? What is stored in the variable?

Comment: In my case it was private and public token for payment gateway, information about price, currency etc. It needed to be accessible within template in order to generate iFrame of payment gateway, but also hidden from user.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a good usercase for a session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my custom payment plugin for Shopware 6 and I used session to solve it.

First inject `session` in your payment handler and then store your variable in the session:

```php
public function pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): RedirectResponse
{
    $returnUrl = $transaction->getReturnUrl();

    $this->session->set('test', 'test1');

    return new RedirectResponse('/checkout/confirm/custom-controller');
}
```

Then read the variable from the session in your controller and pass it to your template:

```php
public function cliffMarketsBerrySimplify(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context, RequestDataBag $dataBag)
{
    $data = $this->session->remove('test');

    return $this->renderStorefront(
        '@plugin/storefront/page/checkout/payment/custom-template.html.twig',
        ['data' => $data]
    );
}
```